# Conditional Operator Return Type with literal digits

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, conditional-operator, return-type

[?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22?_CSHARPKEYWORD%22%29;k%28%22?%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

[Integer literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which
>   its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.

Consider:

```
var value = test ? (Int64)1 : 0;
```

0, a decimal-digit literal with no suffix will be transformed into an `int`.  `int` can be implicitly converted into an `Int64`.  Since this conversion only occurs in one direction, we can feel safe that the return value will be an Int64.

However:

```
var value = test ? (UInt64)1 : 0;
```

`UInt64` and `int` can not be implicitly converted into each other, but yet this code compiles and runs and the resulting type is `UInt64`.

At what point is the type of `0` determined?

If the two types are implicitly castable to each other, then which of the two types will you end up with?  (I don't think this happens normally, but user generated classes could implement such casting.)

Prior Research:
I found several other questions with similar titles, but they were all related to null or nullable types.

Relevance:
This matters in my code because we're immediately passing this result off to ByteWriter.Write, and want to end up with the correct overload that writes the correct number of bytes.  The examples are of course grossly simplified.

Alternate syntax makes the result explicit may be the best option for clarity no matter what is actually happening without the explicit cast:

```
var value = test ? (UInt64)1 : (UInt64)0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that there is one set of implicit conversions between integer types when the numbers are **compile-time constants** (literals), and another set of conversions when they are not constants.

Your interesting example is:

```
var value = test ? (UInt64)1 : 0;
```

which could also be written:

```
var value = test ? 1ul : 0;
```

where the `ul` suffix means `ulong`, i.e. `System.UInt64`.

When literals (constants) are used there does exist an implicit conversion from `int` (`System.Int32`) to `ulong`, but only when that `int` constant is non-negative. It's really the same as:

```
const ulong a = 1ul;
const int b = 0;
var value = test ? a : b;  // also works fine
```

It works, as I said, because of the implicit constant conversion from `int` (since the compiler knows `b` is not negative) to `ulong`.

Now, take away the `const` to get:

```
ulong a = 1ul;
int b = 0;
var value = test ? a : b;  // compile-time error, no implicit conversion in either direction!
```

We see that with non-constants, no implicit conversion in either direction exists, so there's no best common type for `a` and `b` and this fails.

Answer (score 1):

True, a *generic* `int` can't be implicitly converted to `UInt` any length.  But here we are not talking a generic, unknown `int`.  We are talking `0`, which can be converted (even at compile time, which is what I suspect the compiler is doing) into `UInt`.

I'd suggest you using an `int` parameter (or another value the compiler can't infer through data flow analysis) and see what happens.

Comment: I've run into some issues before where it mattered if a value was a constant and I suspect that is related here, but strictly by the quoted documentation this should not work.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore That's what matters, if it is constant or not. The documentation to quote is *[Implicit constant expression conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691286.aspx)*. Note that by the first bullet an `int` ***can*** be converted to `ulong` implicitly (with constants).